# Add vpn extension to plesk

Tags: plesk

I want to add vpn extension to plesk, but i cannot find that extension. Under server managements > extensions there is'not such extension.   Here is picture 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can install it as Plesk extension through Tools&Settings->Updates and Upgrades